# ReactJS : Passing the props without rendering them

Tags: reactjs

Im new on ReactJS.

Im passing the values to the child, and it's rendering fine.

I like props, the rendering is working. But I dont want to render them on my Parent Page .

I want to have access to the props inside the Child Page, but I dont want them to render on my Parent Page ( except for the Link ).

Sorry if Im a bit confusing, Im not sure what tool to use here. Thanks.

**ParentPage.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import ChildPage from './ChildPage.js';

const ParentPage = () => {

  const employees = [{
    name: "shaun",
    id: 1,   
  },
  {
    name: "brian",
    id: 2,   
  },
  {
    name: "geroge",
    id: 3,   
  },
]

return (
  <div>

  {employees.map((employee) => (

    <ChildPage name={employee.name} id={employee.id} />

    <Link to={"/childpage/" + employee.name }> {employee.name} </Link>
 
  ))}

};

export default ParentPage;
```

**ChildPage.js**

```
const ChildPage = (props) => {

  const { name, id } = props


return (
  <div>

  <p> your name is : {name} and your id is : {id} </p>

  </div>
};

export default ChildPage;
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing! What output are you expecting?

Comment: Your question is not clear, you can provide some snapshot of your UI that might help

Comment: The employees array is not correctly initialized, a closing bracket is missing after `},`

Comment: I want to pass the variable I created "employees" without using it yet.
From my ParentPage to my ChildPage.

Comment: Do you want to say without declaring on the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ChildPage` returns

```
<div>

  <p> your name is : {name} and your id is : {id} </p>

</div>
```

which will be rendered to your `ParentPage`. The `<Link>` is not inside your `ChildPage`.

I guess what you meant to do is this:

**ParentPage.js**

```
const ParentPage = () => {

  const employees = [{
    name: "shaun",
    id: 1,   
  },
  {
    name: "brian",
    id: 2,   
  },
  {
    name: "geroge",
    id: 3,   
  },


return (
  <div>

  {employees.map((employee) => (

    <ChildPage name={employee.name} id={employee.id} />
 
  ))}

};
```

**ChildPage.js**

```
const ChildPage = (props) => {

  const { name, id } = props


return (
   <Link to={"/childpage/" + name }> {name} </Link>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete `ChildPage` from `employees.map` in `ParentPage` then it will not be rendered.

I bet you have `ChildPage` in your `router.js` because you have working `<Link />` to your `ChildPage`.

If you want pass the params, just write this against your `<Link />`:

```
<Link to={{ screen: 'childpage', params: { id: employee.id, name: employee.name } }}>
      {employee.name}
</Link>
```

Then, into your `<ChildPage />` you have to receive passed params like this:

```
const ChildPage = ({navigation, route}) => {

  const { params } = route


return (
  <div>

  <p> your name is : {params.name} and your id is : {params.id} </p>

  </div>
};

export default ChildPage;
```